# Docker best practises for managing websites

Tags: docker, docker-machine

What do you think is best practise for running multiple website on the same machine, would you have separate containers set for each website/domain? Or have all the sites in the one container set?

Website 1, Website 2, Website 3:

- nginx
- phpfpm
- mysql

or

Website 1:

- nginx_1
- phpfpm_1
- mysql_1

Website 2:

- nginx_2
- phpfpm_2
- mysql_2

Website 3:

- nginx_3
- phpfpm_3
- mysql_3

Comment: Can't you just run one single nginx reverse proxy talking to phpfpm using `fastcgi_pass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use separate containers for the individual websites but use a single webserver as proxy. This allows you to access all websites of different domains on the same host ports (80/443). Additionally you don't necessarily need to run multiple nginx containers.

Structure:

- Proxy

  - nginx (listens to port 80/443)
- Website 1

  - phpfpm_1
  - mysql_1
- Website 2

  - phpfpm_2
  - mysql_2
- ...

You can use automated config-generation for the proxy service such as [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) that also opens the way to use convenient SSL-certification handling with e.g. [jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/).

The proxy service can then look like this:

- Proxy

  - nginx (listens to port 80/443)
  - docker-gen (creates an nginx config based on the running containers and services)
  - letsencrypt (creates SSL certificates if needed)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if they are not related, I would definitely not put them in the same machine...

Even if you have one website with nginx and mysql I would pull these two apart. It simply gives you more flexibility, and that's what Docker is all about.

Good luck and have fun with Docker!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely isolate each of the applications.

Why?

If they don't rely on each other at all, making changes in one application can affect the other simply because they're running in the same environment, and you wouldn't want all of them to run into problems all at once.